# How do you extract/reuse Docker BuildKit caches with CI

Tags: docker, azure-devops, continuous-integration, docker-buildkit

Docker introduces `RUN --mount=type=cache` which I can work well locally, but I want to be able to leverage it in a CI specifically Azure Devops.

But I can't find a way of `save` and `load` the cache between builds.  Is there an option to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?view=azure-devops#is-reutilizing-layer-caching-during-builds-possible-on-azure-pipelines):

> In the current design of Microsoft-hosted agents, every job is dispatched to a newly provisioned virtual machine (based on the image generated from azure-pipelines-image-generation repository templates). These virtual machines are cleaned up after the job reaches completion, not persisted and thus not reusable for subsequent jobs. The ephemeral nature of virtual machines prevents the reuse of cached Docker layers.

Therefore, the local docker cache on VM cannot be used by another build when you use Microsoft-Hosted agents.

Here are some alternative methods：

1. You could use [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) to execute the docker build process. Multiple builds can share the local cache.
2. You can also you use [Cache task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#docker-images) and `docker save/load commonds` to upload the saved docker layer to azure devops server and restore it on the future run.
3. Use docker pull to pull the image from remote repository. Use using **--cache-from** to point the image.  You could push the build image to remote repository for next build.

You could refer to [this blog](https://andrewlock.net/caching-docker-layers-on-serverless-build-hosts-with-multi-stage-builds---target,-and---cache-from/#using-cache-from-and-target-with-multi-stage-builds) and [this ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6439#issuecomment-663200335) for more detailed info.